# While loop not working as intendet in chatbot with speech to text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyaudio

Hello guys I have a problem with chatbot that is supposted to work with text to speech and speech to text. It's supposted to wait for an input form mic and then answer with with list of answers from SQLite database. However bot gets only my first input that is answered and after that it continues to send my first input over and over again in and infinite loop.

Chatboy is using pyaudio and pygame

At the beggining of chatbots while loop I import response form speech-to-text code. It runs unless it has to repeat itself. It seems that the speech-to-text part of the does not run second time and just skips it completly with already filled answer from first input.

## This is the code that runs the chatbot itself,

while True:

```
print(('Bot: ' + B))
from speak import response  #importing response from speech-to-text code
print(('Host: ' + response))

if response == 'ukončiť':
    print('Program bol úspešne ukončený')
    break
if response == 'vypnúť':
    print('Program bol úspešne ukončený')
    break


words = get_words(B)
words_length = sum([n * len(word) for word, n in words])
sentence_id = get_id('sentence', response)

for word, n in words:
    word_id = get_id('word', word)
    weight = sqrt(n / float(words_length))
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO associations VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (word_id, sentence_id, weight))

connection.commit()



cursor.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results(sentence_id INT, sentence TEXT, weight REAL)')
words = get_words(response)
words_length = sum([n * len(word) for word, n in words])

for word, n in words:
    weight = sqrt(n / float(words_length))
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO results SELECT associations.sentence_id, sentences.sentence, ?*associations.weight/(4+sentences.used) FROM words INNER JOIN associations ON associations.word_id=words.rowid INNER JOIN sentences ON sentences.rowid=associations.sentence_id WHERE words.word=?', (weight, word,))

    
cursor.execute('SELECT sentence_id, sentence, SUM(weight) AS sum_weight FROM results GROUP BY sentence_id ORDER BY sum_weight DESC LIMIT 1')
row = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE results')
tts = gTTS(text=str(row[1]), lang='sk')
tts.save("B.mp3")
mixer.music.load('B.mp3')
mixer.music.play()


if row is None:
    cursor.execute('SELECT rowid, sentence FROM sentences WHERE used = (SELECT MIN(used) FROM sentences) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
    row = cursor.fetchone()
   


B = row[1]
cursor.execute('UPDATE sentences SET used=used+1 WHERE rowid=?', (row[0],))
```

## This is the code that runs speech to text

```
import speech_recognition as sr

from gtts import gTTS
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
 
while True:
  r = sr.Recognizer()

  with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
    print("Tell something!")

    audio = r.listen(source,phrase_time_limit=2)

  try:
    response = r.recognize_google(audio, language='sk-SK')
    break
  except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google nemôže rozoznať audio")
  except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Google error; {0}".format(e))
```

Before the first code there are 2 variables for putting answers into database. I think it's not neccesary for putting it here

Answer (score 0):

You're using `import` wrong.

The first time you import a module, Python will execute all the top-level stuff in that module, and make a note of all functions, variables and other things it defines. On subsequent imports, it just re-uses the stuff from the first time.

When you want to execute code from a module several times, you must place that code inside a function that you can call.

You need to do something like this:

1. Wrap most of the code in your `speak` module inside a function (let's call it `get_speech()` and make it return `response`.
2. At the top of your main module, do `import speak` or `from speak import get_speech`.
3. Where you are now doing `from speak import response`, instead do `response = speak.get_speech()` (or just `response = get_speech()`, depending on what you imported at the top).